# Fastai tabular data - bad result on simple dataset

Tags: fast-ai

I am testing fastai tabular model and getting unexpected results.
Basically, I am trying to predict `y = x * x` using an input dataframe built on random x.

```
from fastai.tabular import *

# Build input dataframe
SIZE = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(SIZE)})
df['y'] = df['x'] ** 2

# Create data object
dep_var = 'y'
cont_names = ['x']
data = (TabularList.from_df(df, cont_names=cont_names)
                           .split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.1)
                           .label_from_df(cols=dep_var, label_cls=FloatList)
                           .databunch())

# Create model and learn
learn = tabular_learner(data, layers=[200,100], metrics=rmse)
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)

#epoch  train_loss  valid_loss  root_mean_squared_error time
#0  0.706821    0.472120    0.467643    00:01
#1  0.275269    0.077311    0.271610    00:01
#2  0.194118    0.133515    0.325397    00:01
#3  0.176048    0.076927    0.187314    00:01
#4  0.163826    0.078179    0.207878    00:01


# Display result
row = df.sample(1).iloc[0]
print(row)
learn.predict(row)  

# Typically:
# x = -1.582047 / y = 2.502874 / predicted_y = 2.324813
```

I'd expect deep learning to perform better so I'm probably doing something wrong here.

Could someone explain why I'm getting such poor results ?

Answer (score 0):

When you square a distribution of random numbers like that, you're bound to wind up with some tiny values of y, which could lead to some floating point arithmetic issues that could affect your results.

Comment: I get the same results with integers.
I also tried with ``y = x * 7`` but results are still quite far away from target.

Comment: Using the default hyperparameters gives a reasonable approximation of the function, which is about what I'd expect. Deep learning isn't a magic formula that will be able to solve something like this perfectly. Deep learning is an approximation of any arbitrary function, not a perfect solution.